# Drawing Tic Tac Toe grid with nested loops in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

My problem is as follows.

I started to sketch out Tic Tac Toe grid with noughts and crosses starting with a row widget. Then I use loop to create three columns as children for the row. In each of these columns I create - using loop again - three containers. The containers are supposed to contain icons representing noughts and crosses. So far so good. See the code below:

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    iconlist[i][j],
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    size: 60,
                    semanticLabel:
                        'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 4)),
                ),
            ])
        ])
```

As you can see, I have a list called iconlist (which is naturally located outside the widget tree). The list is actually a nested list: It has three lists as elements. These elements are lists as well: These sublists represent the rows and they have three icons (type of IconData) each as elements. The code for the list is:

```
    List iconlist = <List>[
  <IconData>[Icons.clear, Icons.radio_button_unchecked, Icons.clear],
  <IconData>[Icons.clear, Icons.radio_button_unchecked, Icons.clear],
  <IconData>[Icons.clear, Icons.radio_button_unchecked, Icons.clear]
];
```

Very logical and viable solution, you might think (and so did I), but Flutter does not like this type of structure at all. When I try to run this application, I get following error (yellow text on red background):

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'IconData' has no instance method '[]'.
> Receiver: Instance of 'IconData' Tried calling:  See also:
> https://flutter.dec/docs/testing/errors

The "funny" thing is that for example iconlist[i + j] works flawlessly. For some weird reason, I cannot get the IconData by subscripting a subscripted list i.e. iconlist[i][j].

What am I doing wrong and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Made my own tic tac toe in Flutter, perfectly working. Watch this tutorial I made, the code for the game is on github, link in the description. Video -
https://youtu.be/Md9kg8HANMQ

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your code and it works without any errors. Please try to run the code below :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
    
List<List<IconData>> iconlist = [
  <IconData>[Icons.clear, Icons.radio_button_unchecked, Icons.clear],
  <IconData>[Icons.clear, Icons.radio_button_unchecked, Icons.clear],
  <IconData>[Icons.clear, Icons.radio_button_unchecked, Icons.clear]
];

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: MyWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
        return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                Expanded(child:Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    Container(
                      child: Icon(
                        iconlist[i][j],
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        size: 60,
                        semanticLabel:
                            'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 4)),
                    ),
                ]))
            ]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is getting interesting. I tried to run your code, and got the same error message:

NoSuchMethodError: Class 'IconData' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance of 'IconData' Tried calling: See also: https://flutter.dec/docs/testing/errors

The situation led me to think that maybe there is something wrong with my configuration, and I tried to run both codes (your and mine) in DartPad (https://dartpad.dev/): Both codes run without any errors, and output is as expected.

The DartPad has Flutter: 1.23.0-18.1.pre and so do I! Any ideas, how I should start troubleshooting this?

Comment: The issue might be with your lint rules. Try declaring iconlist as List<List<IconData>> iconlist or just var iconlist; I've updated the code above please recheck if this works.

Comment: I enabled web: flutter config --enable-web
...and then I typed flutter run -d chrome
...to run a web version in Chrome, and it worked. And after this is started to work also in Android emulator as well. This is weird, indeed. But it is working now whatsoever. :S

I have to emphasize that I had restarted Android emulator previously and even rebooted my computer, and that did not help initially. :|